# Why can't change all the characters from full width character into half width character?

Tags: php

I want to change all the characters  from full width characters into half width characters, write the following codes  to do the job.
For example, to change all full width characters in

```
 Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码
```

into half width characters ,into

```
 codebit.cn - 聚合小段精华代码
```

There are two methods to acheive the goal,but all of them failed.
All the php file were saved as utf-8 format.

method 1:

```
<?php
    function fulltohalf($str){
    $arr=Array( 
    '０' => '0', '１' => '1', '２' => '2', '３' => '3', '４' => '4',  
    '５' => '5', '６' => '6', '７' => '7', '８' => '8', '９' => '9', 
    'Ａ' => 'A', 'Ｂ' => 'B', 'Ｃ' => 'C', 'Ｄ' => 'D', 'Ｅ' => 'E',  
    'Ｆ' => 'F', 'Ｇ' => 'G', 'Ｈ' => 'H', 'Ｉ' => 'I', 'Ｊ' => 'J', 
    'Ｋ' => 'K', 'Ｌ' => 'L', 'Ｍ' => 'M', 'Ｎ' => 'N', 'Ｏ' => 'O',  
    'Ｐ' => 'P', 'Ｑ' => 'Q', 'Ｒ' => 'R', 'Ｓ' => 'S', 'Ｔ' => 'T', 
    'Ｕ' => 'U', 'Ｖ' => 'V', 'Ｗ' => 'W', 'Ｘ' => 'X', 'Ｙ' => 'Y',  
    'Ｚ' => 'Z', 'ａ' => 'a', 'ｂ' => 'b', 'ｃ' => 'c', 'ｄ' => 'd', 
    'ｅ' => 'e', 'ｆ' => 'f', 'ｇ' => 'g', 'ｈ' => 'h', 'ｉ' => 'i',  
    'ｊ' => 'j', 'ｋ' => 'k', 'ｌ' => 'l', 'ｍ' => 'm', 'ｎ' => 'n', 
    'ｏ' => 'o', 'ｐ' => 'p', 'ｑ' => 'q', 'ｒ' => 'r', 'ｓ' => 's',  
    'ｔ' => 't', 'ｕ' => 'u', 'ｖ' => 'v', 'ｗ' => 'w', 'ｘ' => 'x', 
    'ｙ' => 'y', 'ｚ' => 'z', '－' => '-' 
    ); 

    $new = '';            
    foreach ($str as $char){
        if (isset ($arr[$char]))  
            $new .= $arr[$char];    
        else
            $new .= $arr;    
        }
    return $new;
    }

$str="Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码";
echo fulltohalf($str);
?>
```

Error message:

[image]

method 2:

```
<?php
function fulltohalf($Str) { 
    $Queue = Array( 
    '０' => '0', '１' => '1', '２' => '2', '３' => '3', '４' => '4',  
    '５' => '5', '６' => '6', '７' => '7', '８' => '8', '９' => '9', 
    'Ａ' => 'A', 'Ｂ' => 'B', 'Ｃ' => 'C', 'Ｄ' => 'D', 'Ｅ' => 'E',  
    'Ｆ' => 'F', 'Ｇ' => 'G', 'Ｈ' => 'H', 'Ｉ' => 'I', 'Ｊ' => 'J', 
    'Ｋ' => 'K', 'Ｌ' => 'L', 'Ｍ' => 'M', 'Ｎ' => 'N', 'Ｏ' => 'O',  
    'Ｐ' => 'P', 'Ｑ' => 'Q', 'Ｒ' => 'R', 'Ｓ' => 'S', 'Ｔ' => 'T', 
    'Ｕ' => 'U', 'Ｖ' => 'V', 'Ｗ' => 'W', 'Ｘ' => 'X', 'Ｙ' => 'Y',  
    'Ｚ' => 'Z', 'ａ' => 'a', 'ｂ' => 'b', 'ｃ' => 'c', 'ｄ' => 'd', 
    'ｅ' => 'e', 'ｆ' => 'f', 'ｇ' => 'g', 'ｈ' => 'h', 'ｉ' => 'i',  
    'ｊ' => 'j', 'ｋ' => 'k', 'ｌ' => 'l', 'ｍ' => 'm', 'ｎ' => 'n', 
    'ｏ' => 'o', 'ｐ' => 'p', 'ｑ' => 'q', 'ｒ' => 'r', 'ｓ' => 's',  
    'ｔ' => 't', 'ｕ' => 'u', 'ｖ' => 'v', 'ｗ' => 'w', 'ｘ' => 'x', 
    'ｙ' => 'y', 'ｚ' => 'z', '－' => '-' 
); 

return preg_replace("/([\xA3][\xB0-\xB9\xC1-\xDA\xE1-\xFA])/e","\$Queue[\\1]", $Str);
```

}

```
$str = "Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码"; 
echo $str; 
echo "<br />"; 
echo fulltohalf($str); 
?>
```

Error message:

[image]

How to fix two of them?

I solved the method 1 problem ,the fixed codes are as the following.

```
<?php
function fulltohalf($str){
$arr=Array( 
'０' => '0', '１' => '1', '２' => '2', '３' => '3', '４' => '4',  
'５' => '5', '６' => '6', '７' => '7', '８' => '8', '９' => '9', 
'Ａ' => 'A', 'Ｂ' => 'B', 'Ｃ' => 'C', 'Ｄ' => 'D', 'Ｅ' => 'E',  
'Ｆ' => 'F', 'Ｇ' => 'G', 'Ｈ' => 'H', 'Ｉ' => 'I', 'Ｊ' => 'J', 
'Ｋ' => 'K', 'Ｌ' => 'L', 'Ｍ' => 'M', 'Ｎ' => 'N', 'Ｏ' => 'O',  
'Ｐ' => 'P', 'Ｑ' => 'Q', 'Ｒ' => 'R', 'Ｓ' => 'S', 'Ｔ' => 'T', 
'Ｕ' => 'U', 'Ｖ' => 'V', 'Ｗ' => 'W', 'Ｘ' => 'X', 'Ｙ' => 'Y',  
'Ｚ' => 'Z', 'ａ' => 'a', 'ｂ' => 'b', 'ｃ' => 'c', 'ｄ' => 'd', 
'ｅ' => 'e', 'ｆ' => 'f', 'ｇ' => 'g', 'ｈ' => 'h', 'ｉ' => 'i',  
'ｊ' => 'j', 'ｋ' => 'k', 'ｌ' => 'l', 'ｍ' => 'm', 'ｎ' => 'n', 
'ｏ' => 'o', 'ｐ' => 'p', 'ｑ' => 'q', 'ｒ' => 'r', 'ｓ' => 's',  
'ｔ' => 't', 'ｕ' => 'u', 'ｖ' => 'v', 'ｗ' => 'w', 'ｘ' => 'x', 
'ｙ' => 'y', 'ｚ' => 'z', '－' => '-' 
); 

$new = '';
preg_match_all('/./u', $str, $results);
$str=$results[0];            
foreach ($str as $char){
    if (isset ($arr[$char]))  
        $new .= $arr[$char];    
    else
        $new .= $char;   
    }
return $new;
}

echo fulltohalf("Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码");
?>
```

Comment: Please note that in method one you're trying to iterate over $str which is not an array. However you **can** iterate over strings using a for-loop like `for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {  $char = $str[i]; /*...*/ }`

Comment: My goodness, why the custom array? Please see my one-line answer. PHP has a built-in function for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 2:

I've changed `preg_replace` to `preg_replace_callback` and used anonymous function to silence the warning. Your regular expression was wrong, I've changed it. There is simple lookup in anonymous function.

```
<?php
function fulltohalf($Str) { 
    $Queue = Array( 
        '０' => '0', '１' => '1', '２' => '2', '３' => '3', '４' => '4',  
        '５' => '5', '６' => '6', '７' => '7', '８' => '8', '９' => '9', 
        'Ａ' => 'A', 'Ｂ' => 'B', 'Ｃ' => 'C', 'Ｄ' => 'D', 'Ｅ' => 'E',  
        'Ｆ' => 'F', 'Ｇ' => 'G', 'Ｈ' => 'H', 'Ｉ' => 'I', 'Ｊ' => 'J', 
        'Ｋ' => 'K', 'Ｌ' => 'L', 'Ｍ' => 'M', 'Ｎ' => 'N', 'Ｏ' => 'O',  
        'Ｐ' => 'P', 'Ｑ' => 'Q', 'Ｒ' => 'R', 'Ｓ' => 'S', 'Ｔ' => 'T', 
        'Ｕ' => 'U', 'Ｖ' => 'V', 'Ｗ' => 'W', 'Ｘ' => 'X', 'Ｙ' => 'Y',  
        'Ｚ' => 'Z', 'ａ' => 'a', 'ｂ' => 'b', 'ｃ' => 'c', 'ｄ' => 'd', 
        'ｅ' => 'e', 'ｆ' => 'f', 'ｇ' => 'g', 'ｈ' => 'h', 'ｉ' => 'i',  
        'ｊ' => 'j', 'ｋ' => 'k', 'ｌ' => 'l', 'ｍ' => 'm', 'ｎ' => 'n', 
        'ｏ' => 'o', 'ｐ' => 'p', 'ｑ' => 'q', 'ｒ' => 'r', 'ｓ' => 's',  
        'ｔ' => 't', 'ｕ' => 'u', 'ｖ' => 'v', 'ｗ' => 'w', 'ｘ' => 'x', 
        'ｙ' => 'y', 'ｚ' => 'z', '－' => '-' 
    ); 

    return preg_replace_callback(
        "/([\xEF][\x80-\xBF]+)/",
        function($m) use($Queue) {
            if (array_key_exists($m[0], $Queue)) {
                return $Queue[$m[0]];
            } else {
                return $m[0];
            }
        },
        $Str);
}

$str = "Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码"; 
echo $str; 
echo "<br />"; 
echo fulltohalf($str);
```

Answer (score 9):

One line of code:

```
$str="Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码";
$str = mb_convert_kana($str, "rnaskhc", 'UTF-8');
echo $str;
```

and

```
Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码
```

becomes

```
Codebit.cn - 聚合小段精华代码
```

*and* you can keep the case of the letters as a bonus.

Ref: http://php.net/mb_convert_kana

Answer (score 1):

[strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) searches for an occurrence of a string within another string.

You are calling it with a string and an array.

why not just return the corresponding values for the keys?

```
function fulltohalf($str){

    $arr = array('０' => '0', '１' => '1', '２' => '2', '３' => '3', 
                 '４' => '4','５' => '5', '６' => '6', '７' => '7',
                 '８' => '8', '９' => '9','Ａ' => 'A',
                 ....
                );
    $new = '';            //initialise output
    $old = str_split($str); // convert string to array of characters
    foreach ($old as $char){
        if (isset $arr[$char]) //check if the input is a key in the array
            $new .= $arr[$char];   //add to output
        else
            $new .= '_';   //put something to indicate missing/undefined
    }
    return $new;
}
```

It might be inefficient to construct the array on every function call.

You might want to define it in your main function and just pass it to your fulltohalf() function, or not bother with a function at all.

As always in these cases, I will add that you should avoid using mysql in favour of mysqli (improved).

***ADDITIONAL***

If converting from one character set to another, I would use the php functions, rather than reinventing the wheel.

see [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) and [supported encodings](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php)

I can't be sure which encodings you are going from/to, but something like the following might do the trick:

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8","UCS-2")
```

Comment: dear  loopo ,if the string contain multiple characters ,it can't do the job.

Comment: i am sorry that i have changed my question for clearity.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) with arrays of strings, effectively doing a multibyte replace. For example:

```
$str = 'Ｆｏｏｏｏｏ';
echo str_replace(array('Ｆ', 'ｏ'), array('F', 'o'), $str);
```

A probably more robust solution would be using [`mb_convert_kana()`](http://php.net/mb_convert_kana), like so:

```
$str = 'Ｆｏｏｏｏｏ';
echo mb_convert_kana($str, 'a', 'UTF-8'); // change UTF-8 to fit your input charset
```

Both solutions will output:

```
Fooooo
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) I think in this instance it's better to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace). We will search a string for the keys of the queue array and replace them with their corresponding values. This is also a very readable and easy solution.

```
function fulltohalf($str)
{ 
    $queue = [ 
        '０' => '0', '１' => '1', '２' => '2', '３' => '3', '４' => '4',  
        '５' => '5', '６' => '6', '７' => '7', '８' => '8', '９' => '9', 
        'Ａ' => 'A', 'Ｂ' => 'B', 'Ｃ' => 'C', 'Ｄ' => 'D', 'Ｅ' => 'E',  
        'Ｆ' => 'F', 'Ｇ' => 'G', 'Ｈ' => 'H', 'Ｉ' => 'I', 'Ｊ' => 'J', 
        'Ｋ' => 'K', 'Ｌ' => 'L', 'Ｍ' => 'M', 'Ｎ' => 'N', 'Ｏ' => 'O',  
        'Ｐ' => 'P', 'Ｑ' => 'Q', 'Ｒ' => 'R', 'Ｓ' => 'S', 'Ｔ' => 'T', 
        'Ｕ' => 'U', 'Ｖ' => 'V', 'Ｗ' => 'W', 'Ｘ' => 'X', 'Ｙ' => 'Y',  
        'Ｚ' => 'Z', 'ａ' => 'a', 'ｂ' => 'b', 'ｃ' => 'c', 'ｄ' => 'd', 
        'ｅ' => 'e', 'ｆ' => 'f', 'ｇ' => 'g', 'ｈ' => 'h', 'ｉ' => 'i',  
        'ｊ' => 'j', 'ｋ' => 'k', 'ｌ' => 'l', 'ｍ' => 'm', 'ｎ' => 'n', 
        'ｏ' => 'o', 'ｐ' => 'p', 'ｑ' => 'q', 'ｒ' => 'r', 'ｓ' => 's',  
        'ｔ' => 't', 'ｕ' => 'u', 'ｖ' => 'v', 'ｗ' => 'w', 'ｘ' => 'x', 
        'ｙ' => 'y', 'ｚ' => 'z', '－' => '-' 
    ]; 

    return str_replace(array_keys($queue),array_values($queue),$str);
}
```

Note that I had the page in UTF-8 mode by declaring:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Here is my test:

```
$str = "Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码";
echo $str;
echo "<br>";
echo fulltohalf($str);
```

Here are my results:

> Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码
>   Codebit.cn - 聚合小段精华代码

Answer (score 0):

## I just fix your bug.

```
<?php
function fulltohalf($str){
    $arr=Array(
        '０' => '0', '１' => '1', '２' => '2', '３' => '3', '４' => '4',
        '５' => '5', '６' => '6', '７' => '7', '８' => '8', '９' => '9',
        'Ａ' => 'A', 'Ｂ' => 'B', 'Ｃ' => 'C', 'Ｄ' => 'D', 'Ｅ' => 'E',
        'Ｆ' => 'F', 'Ｇ' => 'G', 'Ｈ' => 'H', 'Ｉ' => 'I', 'Ｊ' => 'J',
        'Ｋ' => 'K', 'Ｌ' => 'L', 'Ｍ' => 'M', 'Ｎ' => 'N', 'Ｏ' => 'O',
        'Ｐ' => 'P', 'Ｑ' => 'Q', 'Ｒ' => 'R', 'Ｓ' => 'S', 'Ｔ' => 'T',
        'Ｕ' => 'U', 'Ｖ' => 'V', 'Ｗ' => 'W', 'Ｘ' => 'X', 'Ｙ' => 'Y',
        'Ｚ' => 'Z', 'ａ' => 'a', 'ｂ' => 'b', 'ｃ' => 'c', 'ｄ' => 'd',
        'ｅ' => 'e', 'ｆ' => 'f', 'ｇ' => 'g', 'ｈ' => 'h', 'ｉ' => 'i',
        'ｊ' => 'j', 'ｋ' => 'k', 'ｌ' => 'l', 'ｍ' => 'm', 'ｎ' => 'n',
        'ｏ' => 'o', 'ｐ' => 'p', 'ｑ' => 'q', 'ｒ' => 'r', 'ｓ' => 's',
        'ｔ' => 't', 'ｕ' => 'u', 'ｖ' => 'v', 'ｗ' => 'w', 'ｘ' => 'x',
        'ｙ' => 'y', 'ｚ' => 'z', '－' => '-'
    );

    $new = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
        $char = $str[$i];
        $new .= (isset($arr[$char]))?  $arr[$char]: $char;
    }
    return $new;
}

$str="Ｃｏｄｅｂｉｔ.ｃｎ － 聚合小段精华代码";
echo fulltohalf($str);
?>
```

First, your code used foreach, and I changed to for($i=...) because string is not support foreach syntax(iterating).
Second, your if/else phrase is incompatible with logic.

```
if()$arr[$char]; else $arr; // <- else array!?
```

and I fixed that,

```
if() $converted_char; else $original_char;
```

## Also, you can use another method

everybody says, mb_convert_kana(). yes, that's great solution.